# How to fetch data in specific rows and columns in php using oracle database

Tags: php, oracle, loops, html-table

[image]

This is the table but can you please help me to put data like this

[image]

Here s.no count is incremented and cell name 1 values are from different table.

What I want is to display data of category 1(Car dept) in category 1 rows
category 2(car dept) in category 2 rows and so on in html table

Comment: Is this a problem related to querying the database, or just displaying it on a web page?

Comment: on a html table, (web page) I have the query but I don`t know how to fetch the data in respective rows

Comment: I don't have, nor do I know anyone, that has an Oracle database, so I can't really help you except to point you at the [PHP documentation for querying it](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-assoc.php).

Comment: Please, provide sample data in text format and desired output in text format also. Now it is completely unclear, what the columns you have and what you want to put in each column (because I cannot understand, where are column names and where are column values). Also this type of information can be copypasted as text, which is more readable and at least can be edited easily to make it readable

Comment: And what's your question about this? What have you tried to resolve that question? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample snippet to play with.  [OCI8 manual](https://www.php.net/manual/book.oci8.php)
and [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/underground-php-oracle-manual.html) will also be helpful.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);  // In PHP 5.3 use E_ALL|E_STRICT
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$c = oci_connect('cj', 'cj', 'localhost/orclpdb1');
if (!$c) {
    $m = oci_error();
    trigger_error('Could not connect to database: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}

$s = oci_parse($c, "select * from employees where salary > :sbv");
if (!$s) {
    $m = oci_error($c);
    trigger_error('Could not parse statement: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}
$salary = 15000;
$r = oci_bind_by_name($s, ':sbv', $salary);
if (!$r) {
    $m = oci_error($s);
    trigger_error('Could not bind a parameter: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}
$r = oci_execute($s);
if (!$r) {
    $m = oci_error($s);
    trigger_error('Could not execute statement: '. $m['message'], E_USER_ERROR);
}

echo "<table border='1'>\n";
$ncols = oci_num_fields($s);
echo "<tr>\n";
for ($i = 1; $i <= $ncols; ++$i) {
    $colname = oci_field_name($s, $i);
    echo "  <th><b>".htmlspecialchars($colname,ENT_QUOTES|ENT_SUBSTITUTE)."</b></th>\n";
}
echo "</tr>\n";

while (($row = oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) != false) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        echo "<td>";
        echo $item!==null?htmlspecialchars($item, ENT_QUOTES|ENT_SUBSTITUTE):"&nbsp;";
        echo "</td>\n";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

?>
```